# Capture screenshot of whole scroll layout and save it on sd card

Tags: android, screenshot

I have developed an Android app in which I have to capture a screenshot of the whole scroll layout.

```
String mPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/" + "image.png";  

Bitmap bitmap;
    View v1 = getView().findViewById(R.id.scroll);
    v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(v1.getDrawingCache());
    v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
    OutputStream fout = null;
    imageFile = new File(mPath);

try {
    fout = new FileOutputStream(imageFile);
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, fout);
    fout.flush();
    fout.close();
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) { 
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

But it takes a screenshot of the part appearing on the device's screen only.